# Unable to connect to remote machine in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to launch my jmeter tests in a remote machine as i will be running bulk users on a .jmx file (Approx 200 000 threads). I have a remote machine where i have downloaded jmeter and saved the folder in desktop. and in command prompt i have a command

```
Desktop\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin>jmeter-server -n
Could not find ApacheJmeter_core.jar ...
... Trying JMETER_HOME=..
Found ApacheJMeter_core.jar
Created remote object: <Have a message saying the server is up and running>
```

Now in jenkins i have a command

```
export JAVA_HOME=/java/1.8.0.65
bin//jmeter -n -R <Remote HOst IP> -t file.jmx -l result.jtl -e -o/resultfolder
```

When i trigger the job in jenkins i am getting

```
Configuring remote engine: <Remote machine IP>
Exception creating connection to: <Remote machine IP>; nested exception is: 
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: rmi_keystore.jks (No such file or directory)
Failed to configure <Remote machine IP>
Stopping remote engines
Remote engines have been stopped
Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.RuntimeException: Following remote engines could not be configured:<Remote machine IP>
```

I have a rmi keystore file created in remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to launch `create-rmi-keystore.sh` script on **all machines** and make sure that the configuration is the same, this way communication between JMeter master and slaves will be secure.

More information: [Remote Testing: Setting Up SSL](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html#setup_ssl)

If you don't want the communication between the master and slaves to be secure - you can amend the command line to:

```
jmeter -Jserver.rmi.ssl.disable=true -n -R <Remote HOst IP> -t file.jmx -l result.jtl -e -o/resultfolder
```

or add the next line to *user.properties* file on all hosts to make the change permanent:

```
server.rmi.ssl.disable=true
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up. See [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter) user manual chapter for more information.

---

Depending on your test nature 1 slave might be not enough to simulate 200k threads so make sure you're following recommendations from the [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article and keeping an eye on JMeter engines health using built-in OS tools or [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) as if JMeter will not be able to send requests fast enough - you will get lower throughput/higher response times even if your application is not overloaded.

Comment: I have rmi_keystore.jks file created in all the machine. When i try to start manually from GUI i get error during JRMP  connection establishment, nested exception is : SSLHandshake exception error